# Java close listener for ViewPart

Tags: java, eclipse, view, rcp

I'm using eclipse RCP with a view and I want to print something on the console when the application is closed.

This is what I have done, but It's not working;

```
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent){
   parent.getShell().addListener(SWT.CLOSE, new Listener() {

      @Override
      public void handleEvent(Event event) {
         System.out.println("NOW !");
      }
   });
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found a solution, I needed to add a DisposeListener:

```
parent.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `SWT.Close` event and not `SWT.CLOSE`. From the [SWT Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html):

> SWT.Close - The close event type (value is 21).
>
> SWT.CLOSE - Style constant for close box trim (value is 1<<6, since we do not distinguish between CLOSE style and MENU style).